# How to add new input field in categories “opencart 1.5.6.4”?

Tags: opencart

How to add a new input field in opencart admin categories similar to name or description fields?

Getting error on header and not work

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\wamp\www\opencart\admin\model\catalog\category.php on line 245
```

I tried but not work?

1.Add a 'title' column to the database table 'category_description' .

```
ALTER TABLE `category_description` ADD `title` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

2.In admin/view/template/catalog/category_form.php add after the input for name .

```
<tr>
  <td>Title</td>
  <td><input name="category_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][title]" size="100" value="<?php echo isset($category_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $category_description[$language['language_id']]['title'] : ''; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

3.In admin/model/catalog/category.php

After

```
description = ' " . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . " '
```

Add

```
,title = ' " . $this->db->escape($value['title']) . " '
```

After

```
'description'      => $result['description']
```

Add

```
,'title'             => $result['title'],
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Have you inspected the table `category_description` to make sure the field was added?  Are you using a db prefix in your config file?

Answer (score 1):

First go to the admin language folder. You will find `category.php`,you have to assign tittle value there first, then you fetch that value form the category controller file and assign it on `data[]` array after that you will get that tittle value in the template file.